# Monitor Windows 8 App Connections

Tags: windows-8

Case: I have got a windows 8 tablet and have an app running on it. What I was looking for is a program or a mechanism through which I can be able to monitor all the incoming and outgoing http/https connections that are made by the app which I am monitoring. I am able to do it on the android and ios tablets, but not sure how to do it on a windows 8 tablet.

Is there anything (like an app or a logging program) that I can install on the tablet to monitor connections? Thanks.

Comment: Windows RT edition on an ARM processor, or full-blown Windows running on Intel? For Windows on Intel, [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) might work, though I haven't tried it with Windows Store apps.

Comment: its windows 8 installed on the surface tablet. yes, somebody previously suggested fiddler2, but i haven't tried it yet. I Was wondering if there is some other light weight application other than fiddler/fiddler2 available for this purpose.

Comment: Unless you bought a Surface Pro on launch day (today), the Surface runs Windows RT, so I doubt Fiddler would even run.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) or [NetMon](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=4865) to see the traffic on the network.  Neither will run directly on Windows RT, but that's not necessary.  As long as you are running on the same network with the tablet you are trying to monitor, you can capture all the traffic you want.